# Network Download Test?

Tags: networking, stress-testing

I currently have 2 links of 20 Mbps on my hand and wanted to test them internationally and nationally.

I already have the 2 national links for test but am having problems finding some good international link with 100/1000 Mbps link that will allow me to get the max out of these 2 links I have.

Would appreciate if you guys could point me out some sources that would fit this.

Comment: What does "nationally" mean?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nationally

Comment: If you're stress testing the links then surely you don't need to do this internationally? Your in country link should be sufficient for that.

Comment: @lain ofc I do that does not guarantee they will have the same band free for external network, or they could have a saturated external network for example if they have brought a GigE link for external network and they have the entire GigE in use i would never have a consistent 20 Mbps with the exterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try downloading a couple of Linux Distro isos? They're usually mirrored in various places with high speed links. For example http://centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=15 or http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#mirrors ??

Comment: good idea thanks I will check some of the mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested on www.speedtest.net ?

Comment: Thanks but I need download links for this test. 100mb to 500mb files on a 100 Mbps higher network that is not fully saturated. This is more of a stress test to see how stable the links are.